# How can every Cubone be wearing its dead mothers' skull?

Tags: pokemon

The Pokédex entry for *Pokémon Yellow* says that [Cubone](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Cubone_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) wears its mother's skull:

> Wears the skull of its deceased mother. Its cries echo inside the skull and come out as a sad melody.

This might seem like a reference to the Marowak that was [the ghost of Lavender town](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Marowak_(ghost)) in the Frist Generation games, meaning it's an overgeneralization of a specific instance of a single Cubone's tragic story.

However, similar Pokédex entries appear in nearly ever game, suggesting that many, if not all, Cubone wear their mothers' skulls. *Pokémon Moon*'s entry goes a step farther by suggesting that dealing with its mother's death is a *necessary* part of evolution:

> The skull it wears on its head is that of its dead mother. According to some, it will evolve when it comes to terms with the pain of her death.

How is it logistically possible that every Cubone has a dead mother whose skull it wears, and that they must come to terms with her death in order to evolve? Also, wouldn't that mean a female Cubone/Marowak can only have one child since they only have one skull to give?

Comment: Perhaps Cubone kills its parents? ;) But in all seriousness, even that doesn't make much sense. The ratio is all wrong.

Comment: Applying real-world logic and/or science to cartoons and games is rarely a good idea. In the case of a cartoon about unaccompanied minors travelling around the world enslaving creatures and pitting them in gladiatorial combat...

Comment: A Pokedex is an encyclopedia of scientific knowledge in-universe. Like all scientific theories, they can be incomplete. Just because something represents the current state of scientific knowledge at the moment, doesn't mean that it's the whole story.

Comment: A female marowak has two skulls to give: the one she wears and the one she has. Related: http://awkwardzombie.com/index.php?page=0&comic=011011

Comment: As Cubone's grow up they collect skulls... And then give them to the babies to "teach 'em a lesson".

Comment: @aslum this could work. The skull could be one the mother owned, not the one on her body. The skull of its deceased mother would still be valid if not a bit misleading.

Comment: Alternate solution: mother also means grandmother, great grandmother, etc.

Comment: Alas, @AlfredYerger, what remains to be seen is whether the authors of Pokémon will make full use of the unreliable narrator like that.  From my albeit limited experience, I suppose that it is easier to simply compile and arrange information granted from the authors' notes with little consideration to the status of its in-universe voice.

Comment: I’d say you could as well ask “Why don’t Jessie, James & Meowth die each time they’re ‘blasting off again’”? Or “How could Bugs Bunny breathe on the Moon in ‘Haredevil Hare’”?  Some franchises care more about logic, consistency, common sense, etc., and some care less, and IMHO Pokémon is one of the more broken franchises. So, IMO, the answer to Your question is that there is no answer. Your question is simply another example of the brokenness of the franchise, that’s all.

Comment: @eyeballfrog "It's sculls all the way down"

Comment: Isn't there only one Cubone in the game and therefore in the 'world' ?

Comment: @TylerH Well, you can catch multiple Cubone, and in Generations 2 and later, there are both male and female Cubone, so no.

Comment: @Thunderforge Ah, I've not played or watched much beyond Gen 1.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don’t think this can really be explained in a manner that reconciles Pokedex entries and game or anime information. People have come up with many theories over the years, but none of them really works.

- **Do female Marowak die after giving birth?** But then there would probably end up being a lot more male Cubone than female. They have a 50/50 gender ratio. Besides, purely in terms of game mechanics, your Marowak don’t die if you breed them.
- **Is Cubone an immature Kangaskhan?** This is a theory that was brought up seriously by many players back in the day, but it doesn’t really make sense. It’s just pure speculation.
- **Does Cubone kill its mother?** This doesn’t really make sense, since the Pokedex says that Cubone is sad about her death.

Besides, all of these theories (and basically any other) suffer from the flaw of a replacement ratio: One can easily see that if every Cubone has its mother’s skull (and not its father’s) then there must be at best only one Cubone  for each breeding pair. In other words, the ratio of Cubone to Marowak parents is no better than 1:2. **This is below the viable replacement ratio for a population.**

In my opinion, there’s really only one sensible explanation:

### Pokedex inaccuracy

There are many signs that we shouldn’t take the Pokedex information from the games at face value.

For example, with respect to Marowak, Gold says:

> It collects bones from an unknown place. A Marowak graveyard exists
>   somewhere in the world, rumors say.

However, Crystal presents the same information as fact:

> Somewhere in the world is a cemetery just for Marowak. It gets its
>   bones from those graves.

This suggests that some Pokedex entries are presenting rumor as fact. There are many other examples where Pokedex entries just make no sense. For example, we are told that [Banette](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Banette_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) used to be a plush doll:

> A cursed energy permeated the stuffing of a discarded and forgotten
>   plush doll, giving it new life as Banette. The Pokémon’s energy would
>   escape if it were to ever open its mouth.

But how does this fit with its pre-evolution, [Shuppet](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shuppet_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), which may have been a discarded puppet, but was certainly doesn’t look like a plush doll?

Fire Red tells us that:

> It happened one morning - a boy with extrasensory powers awoke in bed
>   transformed into Kadabra.

But this same information is presented as rumor in Pokemon Sun:

> A theory exists that this Pokémon was a young boy who couldn’t control
>   his psychic powers and ended up transformed into this Pokémon.

And of course, this all makes little sense when we consider that it evolves from Abra, so why would its origin be a little boy?

There are many other examples of Pokedex entries that make little sense, or outright contradict themselves or other Pokedex entries.

In the end, I think the most sensible thing to conclude is that the Pokedex is flawed. **It incorporates myth and rumor as well as research, and sometimes (as the previous examples show) passes them off as fact.**

Comment: I personally subscribe to the ["Pokedex written by a 10-year old"](https://i.imgur.com/Ntv6QJZ.jpg) theory

Comment: This one Cubone is wearing the skull of his mother, that must be true for all Cubones ever!

Comment: These stories sound a lot like the explanation for the first appearance of the Pokémon, not the source of every creature of its species. So you could take it as an explanation for the ancestor of every of these species.

Comment: @Christian That's the way I'm interpreting this.  The pokedex is just not very smart at how it registered things.  If it has a mediocre reason it just runs with it.

Comment: @JMac I'm reffering to the Comic SGR posted, funny stuff

Comment: `the ratio of Cubone to Marowak parents is no better than 1:2` But you are assuming that males and females are born in equal numbers. What if females outnumber males 10 to 1? One male could procreate with 10 females, all of whom die and get their skull used. That ends up as a ratio of 10:11, no? So in essence, the projected ratio of children to parents is equal to the ratio of females to males. And that's not even counting for males to impregnate several generations instead of just their own.

Comment: @Flater Still, that doesn't replace all the females. For every male that is born, you have a minus-1 maximum population of Cubones. So, unless you are breeding them with dittos, you'll run out of females eventually.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the Kangaskhan theory.  It's not that Marowak is an immature Kangaskhan, it's that a Cubone is a child Kangaskhan that lost its mother.  Marowak is an offshoot evolution caused by that pain, that regular Kangaskhan never reach.

Comment: The gender ratio for both Cubone and Marowak is 50% Male, 50% Female. Even if one male Marowak bred with 10 females, 5 of those females would lay eggs containing male Cubones. If, after that, the 10 females al die as you assume, you're left with 1 male Marowak, 5 Male Cubones, and 5 female Cubones. So the ratio is 6:5, and that's only if all the Cubones evolve, and even then, only 5 of them will evolve into female Marowak.

Comment: As for this answer, you assume that only Marowak can breed with other Marowak. We know this not to be the case. _Any_ Pokemon in the same egg group, plus Ditto, can breed with a Marowak and produce an egg containing a Cubone.

Comment: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Monster_(Egg_Group) <- Full list of Pokemon that can produce a Cubone egg by being a male of that species breeding with a female Marowak.

Comment: Can it be assumed that Cubones produce litters rather than a single offspring at a time?  That at least solves the population sustainability issue.  Though only one per litter could take the mother's skull.  Perhaps each child gets a piece of the skull, and installs it in a decorative facade that replicates the remainder?  Or one gets the skull, and the others don fake skulls out of jealousy and/or shame?

Comment: What happens when you breed a male Marowak with a Ditto?

Comment: @Flater - I am not assuming it, per se. That is their gender ratio from the games.

Comment: Several of Grimer's entries claim it came to life when "the moon's X-rays" shined onto sludge. On top of the moon itself not being a significant source of X-rays, most of the sun's X-rays are blocked by the atmosphere. So it's even less likely any reflecting off the moon would make it. Pokedex is *littered* with nonsense. +1

Comment: Male Marowak X Ditto = Cubone egg, that still somehow hatches wearing a skull. Maybe they can change gender to fulfil parental roles, like some fish do, and the dad's like "Welp, turns out its mother is actually a purple gelatinous blob, better change gender and die".

Comment: The Pokedex is known through the series to be based on the discovery of scientists. Prof Oak says that the Pokedex is a new invention, so since it changes its fair to assume they update it whenever they discover new data.

If there was nothing left to discover, professors and researchers would not exist, other than to give the new trainers their Pokemon.

Comment: What if Pokémon works off of some kind of weird science and magic and in reality the marrowak can somehow grow back its skull? To be frank though, Professor Oak is pretty old and possibly a little... rusty at science (just speculation based on age and nothing more). Maybe the pokedex entry is meant to reflect you finding that one marrowak and the others just happen to have skulls for other reasons? Perhaps it's a helmet that grows back every season like antlers? I don't know what to say. It's also possible the pokedex was programmed to assume only one instance of each Pokémon exists...(cont.)

Comment: ...and therefore it just picks up new data based on its own observations. It might not even be filled up already. Might be an AI based system to machine learn the different Pokémon. After all, only shinies and males and females look different *and even that took a long while to differentiate*. Note this isn't an answer. I'm just randomly speculating.

Comment: The population being below the viable replacement rate would actually fit with the game - as Blue says in Lavender Town: "How's your POKéDEX coming, pal? I just caught a CUBONE! I can't find the grown-up MAROWAK yet! I doubt there are any left!"

Answer (score 21):

In the first game, the Pokedex is considered a recent innovation, to the point that Professor Oak, a leading expert on Pokemon, has only just received one.
From this, it is possible to assume that your journey in Pokemon Red, Blue, and Yellow are a part of Professor Oak's research using this new tool.

Professor Oak describes the Pokedex as "a high tech encyclopedia", which is to say it is a device used to aggregate information on a subject, rather than a tool for observation or measurement.

Since data is only recorded AFTER you catch a Pokemon, this may mean that Pokemon you catch are studied by Oak, and his findings and notes are uploaded to some sort of cloud information hub which your Pokedex can access. This would be consistent with being the bleeding edge of technology, as the recent development of the internet in the Pokemon world is considered significant news, as evidenced by talking to the man outside of Oaks lab, and Bill's relative fame for his contributions. Therefore the newest technological innovations coming out would be relating to long distance digital telecommunication.

Therefore, it is feasible that your adventure in the original Pokemon games were the foundation for the data available on Cubone in all subsequent pokemon games. The Pokedex, in this case, would be acting as a sort of Wikipedia for researchers to share notes on their observations of Pokemon, and what you see in accounts of Cubone are simply the originals notes Oak took on the Lavender town Cubone in the care of Mr. Fuji.

In Pokemon Crystal, the entry given for Cubone is

> It lost its mother after its birth. It wears its mother's skull, never revealing its true face.

This is written in a style that seems to indicate an individual, rather than speaking of a broad group, which might support this. Additional evidence would be the very premise of the games. In Pokemon Red and Blue Oak sends you on your mission to fulfil his dream of creating a comprehensive listing of all Pokemon, however the Pokedex knows information you could not possibly know yourself, such as the local distributions of Pokemon in areas you have not visited. The combination of the fact that Oak requires you to go on your journey to complete the Pokedex along with the fact that the Pokedex updates with data you cannot have learned yourself indicates that some of this data must be coming from an external source, namely Oak.

Thus, the inconsistent/implausible data for Cubone can be attributed to an oversight of researchers in the Pokemon world, not updating Cubone's entry with more accurate data after Oak's original survey. As to the real explanation for Cubone, it is likely that Cubones and Marowaks in general are mamalian scavenger pokemon which have developed rudimentary tool use, specifically using bones from their findings. Typically they use the bones picked from corpses as armor and weaponry to defend themselves from predators,  particularly using skulls of larger pokemon to protect their heads. The Cubone from the original games in particular used it's mother's bones after it's death, but this is not always the case.

Answer (score 4):

Cubone mothers clearly grow and shed an extra head with every child born.

This permits each child to get a skull, and a mother Cubone to have more than one child (as in-game breeding demonstrates).

As the head of the Cubone carries its identity, once a head has been shed in a sense their mother is dead.  The new head has the same body, and even claims the same (mother's) skull, but the eyes are just not the same.  To the child, their mother has died.

They are sad, but carry (their mother's skull) on.

In game breeding elides this difficulty; this is a game for children, after all, and the messy biological details of Pokemon reproduction not covered.

Answer (score -2):

A possibility: when an Abra loses his mother, it becomes a Cubone. Without a parent to teach how to use its psychic powers it goes feral. It can still move bones telekinetically (bonemerang) but can't do any of the fancier stuff.

This however doesn't address *breeding* Cubones, at which point I'm stumped.

Comment: Welcome to Sci-fi/Fantasy Stack Exchange! Do you have anything to back up your claim that an Abra becomes Cubone from the games, anime, or other media? Both of the other answers right now cite things in the games to back up their answers, rather than being just pure speculation.

Comment: While this answer could certainly be improved, it’s not spam, or even deletion-worthy, it does try  to address the question (Cubone comes from Alakazam or whatever, most of which don’t produce Cubone and thus propagate.